# How to show pdf file located in asset folder using flutter pdf package

Tags: flutter, pdf

I'm currently using https://pub.dev/packages/pdf package for generate a pdf.
now I want to open a pdf file in my asset folder (pdf file location assets/pdfs/pdf_file.pdf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use default PdfPreview widget, it requires `Future<Uint8List>` and you can provide it using `(await rootBundle.load(filePath)).buffer.asUint8List()`.

```
   String filePath = 'assets/pdfs/pdf_file.pdf';

    return PdfPreview(
      build: (format) async => (await rootBundle.load(filePath)).buffer.asUint8List()
    );
```